# When I console.log(req.user), it allways undefined although I console.log(req), it show all infor about this session

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

it is the result when I console.log(req)

```
 sessions:
  [Object: null prototype] {
    W0Hf0EhynlOrE8zk8fXYSv7DrkwmT9UA:
     '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":{"ID":9,"TenDangNhap":"mrhauphan","Email":"mrhauphan@gmail.com","Password":"$2b$10$Cngpb.5KHcrCWWuhYy1Tx.AxFpG5GAwGVDOr9jPmXslAFDS8lxTbO","Quyen":"","HoTen":"Phan Văn Hậu","NgaySinh":"15/07/1998","ButDanh":"","ID_CMQL":0,"NgayConLai":0}}}' },
 generate: [Function] },
```

sessionID: 'W0Hf0EhynlOrE8zk8fXYSv7DrkwmT9UA',
  session:
   Session {
     cookie:
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true },
     passport: { user: [Object] } },

Comment: Maybe you are not deserializing user properly

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the object you show in the post, you most likely need to do something like console.log(req.session.passport.user). From what I can see, the request does not have a user object directly on it, it exists on a nested child object.